# How to set first and second child of ordered list to have the same indentation?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
1 text
1.1 text
2 text
2.1 text
    2.1.1 text
    2.1.2 text
3. text
3.1 text
    3.1.1 text
    3.1.2 text
    3.1.3 text
```

The parent i.e 1, 2, 3 will not have any indentation. Same goes to its first child i.e 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 as you can see on code above.

My current code:

```
<style>
    ol {
        list-style-type: none;
        counter-reset: item;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

```
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            Text
        </li>
        <li>
            Text
            <ol>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Text
            <ol>
                <li>text</li>
                <li>text</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>text
            <ol>
                <li>text
                </li>
                <li>text
                </li>
                <li>text
                    <ol>
                        <li>text
                        </li>
                        <li>text
                        </li>
                        <li>text
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>text
                    <ol>
                        <li>text
                        </li>
                        <li>text
                        </li>
                        <li>text
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>text
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

The result:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UinX5.png)

How do I remove the indentation (eg. 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4) and make it same level indent with its parent (1,2,3,4)?

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  font-weight: bold;
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

body>ol>li>ol ol {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      Text
    </li>
    <li>
      Text
      <ol>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Text
      <ol>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>text
      <ol>
        <li>text
        </li>
        <li>text
        </li>
        <li>text
          <ol>
            <li>text
            </li>
            <li>text
            </li>
            <li>text
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>text
          <ol>
            <li>text
            </li>
            <li>text
            </li>
            <li>text
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>text
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: are we allowed to put <ol> inside <li> tag? My senior told me I'm not allowed to do so because there will be an error when parsing it. btw, I'm converting html to pdf using dompdf and it seems like dompdf does not allowed that

Comment: It looks valid to me (I've just copied your html, by the way).

Comment: Make sure you are running your html through a validator and you are using the HTML5 parser: `$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);`

Answer (score 1):

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol > li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0;    
}
ol > li > ol > li:before {
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  display: table-cell;
}


li ol > li {
  margin: 0;
}

li ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>text
    <ol>
      <li>text</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
  <li>text
    <ol>
      <li>text
        <ol>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
<li>text
    <ol>
      <li>text
        <ol>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
```

I think this is what you have expected.