# CSS: Limit indentation on nested <ul>

Tags: css

I have a nested `<ul>` list that is rendered like this:

```
- 1
  - 1.1
    - 1.1.1
      - 1.1.1.1
        - 1.1.1.1.1
        - 1.1.1.1.2
      - 1.1.1.2
      - 1.1.1.3
    - 1.1.2
  - 1.2
```

I'd like to limit with CSS the maximum depth of how the list is rendered (not the maximum level of list nesting. The html should remain exactly the same) to, say, 3 levels, so the list is rendered like this:

```
- 1
  - 1.1
    - 1.1.1
    - 1.1.1.1
    - 1.1.1.1.1
    - 1.1.1.1.2
    - 1.1.1.2
    - 1.1.1.3
    - 1.1.2
  - 1.2
```

Can it be done with just CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set first and second child of ordered list to have the same indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244606/how-to-set-first-and-second-child-of-ordered-list-to-have-the-same-indentation)

Comment: Related, but not the same question, I think. That question asks how to set the same indentation for the first two levels, and from then on continue with the regular nesting. I''m asking for quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the nested lists starting from a particular depth:

```css
ul > li > ul > li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>aaaa</li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>aaaa</li>
              <li>aaaa</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>aaaa</li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>aaaa</li>
              <li>
                <ul>
                  <li>aaaa</li>
                  <li>aaaa</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>aaaa</li>
</ul>
```

Or like this:

```css
ul > li > ul > li > ul > li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>aaaa</li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>aaaa</li>
              <li>aaaa</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>aaaa</li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>aaaa</li>
              <li>
                <ul>
                  <li>aaaa</li>
                  <li>aaaa</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>aaaa</li>
</ul>
```